# Is there / should there be a naming convention for expl3 extensions?

Tags: package-writing, expl3, naming

In other programming languages, there is a (sometimes pretty loose) standard on how to name modules / packages / etc. Does `expl3` have such a convention in place or, if not, what should it be?

Say you created a `Shape` object (for whatever reason) for LaTeX and you wished to publish it to CTAN (for whatever reason).
Would you name it:

- `ltx3shape`
- `expl3shape` (weird, since in the future it won't be 'experimental' anymore)
- `ltx3-shape`
- `latex3-shape`
- ...
- ???

Comment: Maybe section 3 “The naming scheme” of [`expl3`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/expl3/) document?

Comment: @LeoLiu My apologies, I meant the naming of the entire package.

Comment: Make the name memorable. I would hate it if all packages had the same prefix, as it makes it difficult to go through a sorted list of packages and they are all starting at the letter 'e'.

Comment: I don't think there is and I don't think there should be. take `siunitx` as an example for a package based on expl3: the name refers to the functionality and not the underlying programming layer.

Comment: @SeanAllred: I don't think you need to use any special name. The package users do not care about whether `fontspec`, `xeCJK`, `chemmacros`, etc. are written in LaTeX3 syntax or not.

Comment: I think the only limitation of package names is the prefix `l3<name>`. The L3-Team uses the prefix for their modules.

Comment: It's important to note that these packages are specifically not for the end user; they are extensions to `expl3` itself. At least for end user packages, I'd agree that there need be no hint as to its implementation format. There may not need to be for the other either, but it's worth exploring. These packages are *only* for package authors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For most packages, the link to LaTeX3/`expl3` is really one for the programmer to worry about. As such, they should be named to help the end user find the functionality and not necessarily 'mention' `expl3` at all.

For code specifically seeking to add ideas to the programming layer, the current approach seems to be for programmers to use `lt3...`. Presumably, some of these ideas, if widely taken up, will end up with 'kernel' level module names as they will be adopted or adapted by the team, but others may well remain 'outside' the core.